# What does「程よく埋もれたい感」mean here?

Tags: manga

The guys were arguing which physique is more attractive.

[image]

I'm lost on understanding the 隙間も程よく埋もれたい感の圧勝だろ part. Does 程よく埋もれたい感 mean "feeling of wanting to be covered" or something? What 感 means here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this 感【かん】 is a noun, and it's sometimes used like a colloquial suffix meaning "feeling", "atmosphere", or simply "-ness". This 埋もれたい感 refers to 'I-wanna-be-covered (sort of) atmosphere/attractiveness'. (Still, I don't quite get what the second guy is trying to say with this much of the context. Maybe he is comparing the "slits" of the two girls, or maybe he is saying 埋もれたい感 is better than a "slit".)